# SQL Update column with data from another table

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have 2 tables below

```
DEVICES
--------------------
DEVICE_ID   MODEL_ID
1           A
2           B
3           C
4           D


CHANGE_VALUES
----------------------------------------
D_ID    CHANGE_MODEL_ID
1           E
4           F
```

Now I'd like to update the value of `MODEL_ID` in `DEVICES` table for all the `DEVICE_ID` having values listed in `D_ID` in table `CHANGE_VALUES`.

The SQL query I used to achieve the objective is shown below. However, it does not seem to be a good solution since for every value of `DEVICE_ID` , it is required to perform 2 sub-queries. Running this on CHANGE_VALUES containing ~ 3k rows took me 34 seconds, which seems to be long.

```
UPDATE devices dev
SET dev.model_id =
   (SELECT c_value.change_model_id
    FROM change_values c_value
    WHERE dev.device_id = c_value.d_id
   )
WHERE 1        IN
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM change_values c_value
  WHERE dev.device_id = c_value.d_id
  );
```

As I'm new to SQL, I don't know if there is any existing ways that can do the same thing. So I'm curious to know if is there any better solutions.

Note: I'm using Oracle 10g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your biggest problem is that you're issuing a `COUNT(*)` for each row in `devices` - that's not what you actually need to do; you'll want an `EXISTS` clause instead.  The following should work for any RDBMS:

```
UPDATE Devices d SET model_id = (SELECT c.change_model_id
                                 FROM Change_Values c
                                 WHERE c.d_id = d.device_id)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM Change_Values c
              WHERE c.d_id = d.device_id);
```

Obviously, this is presuming you have an index on `Devices.device_id`.  One on `Change_Values.d_id` may also speed things up.

Comment: Great, didn't know that is where the problem. Now I could bring the execution time down to 1/2 second from 1/2 minute using your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
update devices a set model_id=(select change_model_id from change_values b where b.d_id=a.device_id) 
where device_id in (select d_id from change_values)
```